# Questions related to UX Management

Tags: feature-request

I know the UX stackexchange is focused more on the day to day, practical aspects of UX but I was wondering if we could add a tag for "management" to address questions like, how to manage teams, how to do critiquing, how to improve collaboration, etc.? Would this belong here or does this warrant another site?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a question, go ahead and ask and add the management tag. We might determine that it's off topic. We might even determine that all questions along those lines are off topic. But I prefer to defer such decisions to the last responsible moment (when we have more information). It's the agile way. :)

Comment: Makes sense to me, guess I better start answering questions to get those points.

Answer (score 1):

Although there is clearly overlap, if I have a question on managing a designer, I would want to hear from design managers, not just random managers.  I think it's a perfectly relevant question to a UX community.  I continue to be saddened by how narrowly people interpret this service.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the overlap with [general management](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/25641/management-and-leadership), [product](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/28281/product-management) or [project](http://pm.stackexchange.com) management is far too great to justify this, and we'll be getting a ton of questions which belong there (in case the former two make it to a public beta).

Comment: Agreed, there's lots of Agile type stuff over there and I'm sure the more general skills of project/ect management are much more relevant in most situations for communication/ect

Comment: I see your point but management of UX to me just seems like it's such a different beast. As a designer, it's not about being managed by pesky PMs but rather it's about being driven/mentored by a Creative Director who's looking to unleash your potential. That's the type of management I'm thinking would go towards UX - as opposed to the generic PM/Product kinda thing.